# AWSIoTManager -createKeysAndCertificateFromCsr result is "Missing Authentication Token"

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to creates keys and certificate by using **createKeysAndCertificateFromCsr** function and the result comes from block.

```
[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionAPNortheast2
                                                                                                    credentialsProvider:nil];
AWSIoTManager *awsIoTManager = [AWSIoTManager defaultIoTManager];

// CSR information dictionary
/*
 commonName
 countryName;
 organizationName;
 organizationalUnitName;
 */
NSString *commonName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];

NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSString *countryName = [usLocale displayNameForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode value:countryCode];

NSString *organizationName = [[NSBundle mainBundle].bundleIdentifier componentsSeparatedByString:@"."][1];
NSString *organizationalUnitName = [[NSBundle mainBundle].bundleIdentifier componentsSeparatedByString:@"."][2];;

NSLog(@"commonName = %@ \
      commonName = %@ \
      organizationName = %@ \
      organizationalUnitName = %@",commonName, countryName, organizationName, organizationalUnitName);

NSDictionary <NSString *, NSString *> * csrDictionary = @{@"commonName":commonName,
                                                          @"countryName":countryName,
                                                          @"organizationName":organizationName,
                                                          @"organizationalUnitName":organizationalUnitName};

// Create CSR
[awsIoTManager createKeysAndCertificateFromCsr:csrDictionary
                                      callback:^(AWSIoTCreateCertificateResponse *mainResponse) {
```

When I check the parameter of block. It was nil with this error message.

> Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSIoTErrorDomain Code=0 "Missing Authentication Token" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing Authentication Token, NSLocalizedFailureReason=MissingAuthenticationTokenException}

Give me some suggest. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you need to provide a valid `AWSCredentialsProvider`.
Either a `AWSStaticCredentialsProvider` where you use the access and secret keys (not recommended for things other than testing), or depending on your setup one of the other available providers like `AWSWebIdentityCredentialsProvider` or `AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider`. They are all declared in the `AWSIdentityProvider.h` file.

Comment: You right. But I tried to find the way except AWSCredential provider and finally I found it. Thank you anyway! Your answer is right way.

Comment: Another way is to use an anonymous credentials provider and connect using a certificate, but that requires to have a mechanism to generate certificates...